# How to efficiently select only columns which contain variation in values for a given subset of rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For context, my ultimate goal is to remove *nearly-duplicated* rows from a very large dataframe. Here is some dummy data:

```
+---+--------+----------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
|key|unique_1|  unique_2|...|col_125|col_126|...|col_414|col_415|
+---+--------+----------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
|  1|     123|01-01-2000|...|      1|   true|...|    100|     25|
|  2|     123|01-01-2000|...|      0|  false|...|    100|     25|
|  3|     321|12-12-2012|...|      3|   true|...|     99|      1|
|  4|     321|12-12-2012|...|      3|  false|...|     99|      5|
+---+--------+----------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
```

In this data, combinations of observations from *unique_1* and *unique_2* should be distinct, but they aren't always. When they are repeated, they have the same values for the vast majority of the columns, but have variation on a very small set of other columns. I am trying to develop a strategy to deal with the near-duplicates, but it is complicated because each set of near-duplicates has a different set of columns which contain variation.

I'm trying to see the columns that contain variation for a single set of near-duplicates at a time - like this:

```
+---+-------+-------+
|key|col_125|col_126|
+---+-------+-------+
|  1|      1|   true|
|  2|     20|  false|
+---+-------+-------+
```

or this:

```
+---+-------+-------+
|key|col_126|col_415|
+---+-------+-------+
|  3|   true|      1|
|  4|  false|      5|
+---+-------+-------+
```

I've successfully gotten this result with a few different approaches. This was my first attempt:

```
def findColumnsWithDiffs(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    df.columns.foldLeft(df){(a,b) =>
        a.select(b).distinct.count match {
            case 1 => a.drop(b)
            case _ => a
        }
    }
}

val smallFrame = originalData.filter(($"key" === 1) || ($"key" === 2))
val desiredOutput = findColumnsWithDiffs(smallFrame)
```

And this works insofar as it gave me what I want, but it is so **unbelievably** slow. It is approximately 10x slower for the function above to run then it takes to display all of the data in `smallFrame` (and I think that the performance only gets worse with the size of the data - although I have not tested that hypothesis thoroughly).

I thought that using `fold` instead of `foldLeft` might yield some improvements, so I rewrote the `findColumnsWithDiffs` function like this:

```
def findColumnsWithDiffsV2(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    val colsWithDiffs = df.columns.map(colName => List(colName)).toList.fold(Nil){(a,b) =>
        df.select(col(b(0))).distinct.count match {
            case 1 => a
            case _ => a ++ b
        }
    }

    df.select(colsWithDiffs.map(colName => col(colName)):_*)

}
```

But performance was the same. I also tried was to map each column to the number of distinct values it has and work from there, but again performance was the same. At this point I'm out of ideas. My hunch is that the filter is being performed for each column which is why it is so terribly slow, but I don't know how to verify that theory and/or change what I'm doing to fix it if I'm correct. Does anyone have ideas to improve the efficiency of what I'm doing?

I'm currently using spark 2.1.0 / scala 2.11.8

Comment: you need more examples. given what you are doing may be the performance is relatively OK. Very large is?

Comment: @thebluephantom The dataframe I want to work with is hundreds of columns and approximately a billion rows. The data I have been working with to write the functions is a million rows and 40 columns. I know the size of the data means it will be slow. But to take 10x longer than to show all the data for those rows, to me seems like a red flag.

Comment: not so sure that is true

Comment: So you basically want to drop all columns which have another column which is the same except for X (1) samples?

Comment: I'm sorry Assaf, I don't fully understand your question.In the data I have, there is a combination of columns that should yield a single observation. "unique_1" and "unique_2" in the dummy data - the observation of "123", "01-01-2000" should only appear once. But when I am looking at the two rows that have the repeat values, there is too much overlap and it is very hard to identify what the differences are. My goal is to filter the data to a single set of duplicated values in the "unique" columns and then return only the columns that have different values for those two (sometimes more) rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the approaches to identifying the distinct values are fine, the issue is with the lazy evaluation of the filter. To improve performance, call `smallFrame.cache` before using `findColsWithDiffs`. This will save the filtered data in memory, which will be fine because it is only a few rows at a time.